# Probability of a team scoring a goal?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, games

I am trying to work out the probability of teams scoring a goal in a football match. Obviously there are many factors to consider, and the probability is impossible to predict correctly as there are many factors that will change in a football match. However i want to figure out the probability using only the following information. A lot of work has been done on predicting football matches using poisson distribution, but in this case, i only want it to be based on the stats that i have.

So for this example it is **Team A** vs **Team B**.

**Team A** Scores in 70% of their home matches **(a)**
**Team B** Concedes in 50% of their away matches **(b)**

**Team B** Scores in 10% of their away matches **(c)**
**Team A** Concedes in 30% of their home matches **(d)**

I have managed to calculate the probability of a goal by using the following formula:

(a+c)-(a*c)

I believe this calculation to be correct but it only takes into account the stats for **team A** or **team B** SCORING, it does not take into account the stat of the opposite team conceding.

So basically i am after a formula that takes into consideration **team A**'s ability to score against **team B**'s ability to concede, and the same for **team B** to score and **team A** to concede.

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem where mathematics can at best supply a "toy" answer, as there is so much more to sporting outcomes than simple statistics.

But this looks fun, so let's crack on with it anyway.  Take everything that follows with a pinch of salt.

We have two estimates, $a$ and $b$ for **team A** scoring.  Let's go with the average, $(a+b)/2=0.6$, and say that's equal to $\mathbb{P}(S_A)\ge 1$, the probability that the number of goals scored by **team A**, $S_A$, is at least 1.  Let's model $S_A$ as a [homogeneous Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process#Homogeneous), which therefore has rate parameter $\lambda_{AB}=-\log\left(1-(a+b)/2\right)\approx 0.916$.  This means we expect **team A** to score $k$ goals against **team B** with probability $e^{-\lambda_{AB}}\lambda_{AB}^k/k!$, like this:

```
goals | probability
------+------------
  0   |   40.0%
  1   |   36.7%
  2   |   16.8%
  3   |    5.1%
  4   |    1.2%
  5   |    0.2%
```

Similarly, the number of goals that **team B** scores against **team A** could be modelled as Poisson with rate $\lambda_{BA}=-\log\left(1-(c+d)/2\right)\approx 0.223$, with the probabilities working out like:

```
goals | probability
------+------------
  0   |   80.0%
  1   |   17.9%
  2   |    2.0%
  3   |    0.1%
```

Finally, we treat those independently (multiply the probabilities) to find the most likely overall scores:

```
score A : B | probability
------------+------------
      0 : 0 |   32.0%
      1 : 0 |   29.3%
      2 : 0 |   13.4%
      0 : 1 |    7.1%
      1 : 1 |    6.5%
      3 : 0 |    4.1%
```

So there we are.  But please don't put any money on it!